# How Java Program can be tuned or worked directly with available RAM (32 GB) and muti-core CPU processor

Tags: memory, jvm, ram

I have a high end machine with 32 GB and I want to effectively utilize the available RAM for Java Process. Practically, I have seen I can run at max 3 JBoss instances (or Java Process) with Max 3GB Heap Size in one box still I have 20GB free space not utilized.  Is it possible to create Java Program that can effectively directly work with RAM like C++, not relying on Java Memory Model for creating objects on JVM and also not relying on GC to reclaim memory. I mean Java Program directly working with RAM